# SVG/JavaScript: Trying to select and change polygon point

Tags: javascript, ipad, google-chrome, svg, safari

I'm trying to select and alter the 2nd point in the polygon shape below with JavaScript. My intent is to move it horizontally depending on the browser width so that it'll point towards something in my overall design.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="100px" width="100%">
  <polygon id="wedge" points="100,1 38,10 0,1 0,0 100,0"></polygon>
</svg>
```

This is the JavaScript function that deals with the adjustment of the 2nd polygon point:

```
var wedge = document.getElementById('wedge');
var browserWidth = window.innerWidth;
var contentWidth = 960;
var margin = 80;

function wedgeAdjust() {
  var breakpoint = contentWidth + (2 * margin);

  if (browserWidth > breakpoint) {
    wedge.points[1].x = (((browserWidth - contentWidth) / 2) / browserWidth) * 100;
  } else if (browserWidth <= breakpoint) {
    wedge.points[1].x = (margin / browserWidth) * 100;
  }
}
```

This function is fired when the page is loaded and when the browser is resized (on resize the browserWidth variable is updated first).

My problem is this:
Everything works fine in chrome, but on my iPad (Safari), nothing happens. I tried adding an alert like so:

```
alert(wedge.points);
```

This gives me "[Object SVGPointList]" in both browsers. But things get interesting when I change it to the specific point I want to alter like so:

```
alert(wedge.points[1]);
```

This gives me the following in chrome: [Object SVGPoint] (which is cool since it lets me chage the x value). But on the iPad (Safari) I'm returned "undefined". Making the function as a whole fail.

What am I doing wrong? Any help and feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wedge.points` is an object of type `SVGPointList`, which doesn't seem to support subscript access (`[ ]`) by standard.

You should use `wedge.points.getItem(1)` instead of `wedge.points[1]`.

Source: [Microsoft SVGPointList documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff972110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Please upvote if it helped you, it helps show future users that it's a good quality answer :)

Comment: I'd love to, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet :/

Comment: Opera did it first, Firefox followed and I think Chrome supports it too now. I suspect it will be part of SVG 2 if it isn't already. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=631437 is the Firefox bug.